# Adding Cc, Bcc and Subject fields to a message in an email sending Android app

Tags: android

I am making an email sending application on Android. Only To field is visible when I launch my application through a button click.

Why doesn’t it show Cc, Bcc and Subject fields? How to add these fields to my app? And how to show a default email address in the To field? (Now nothing is written in the To field by default.)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendemail);
clickBtn.setText("Send email");
clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String aEmailList[] = { "user@fakehost.com","user2@fakehost.com" };
        String aEmailCCList[] = { "user3@fakehost.com","user4@fakehost.com"};
        String aEmailBCCList[] = { "user5@fakehost.com" };
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");
        startActivity(emailIntent);
        //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: you want add bcc & cc manually (at dynamic) or by coding...?

Comment: so, cc & bcc are not coming in layout?

Comment: i clear my app and restart the eclipse then launch new emulator then it works...thanks and soory for waisting  ur precious time for me on it...

Comment: What type is aEmailBCCList?

Answer (score 22):

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] { "documents@4taxcash.com" });
```

You just had to make the second parameter a string array

Answer (score 1):

EXTRA_CC is deprecated
but is this way maybe resolve:

> ### ...
>
> intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:someone@theirsite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com"));
>
> ### ...

Comment: It's not deprecated according to the current docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_CC

Answer (score 0):

Best solution of this problem is

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:emample@gmail.com?bcc=sampleEmail2@gmail.com&subject=subject text ...&body= extra text ")
        startActivity(intent)
```