# Debugging an Android intent problem (no specific receivers)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem that I want in my application to have a specific email receiver whenever the user press the email button it shows to him/her a fixed receiver. How can I do this?

```
 public void google(View v){
       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});
       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
       Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"");
       shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(shareIntent);

 }
```

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwp33.png)

[this is the image of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSbag.png)

Comment: paste your code not image

Comment: please see this link  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843068/10989990

Comment: What do you mean by email receiver? Are you trying to directly open a specific email application? If that is the case then you will need to know the package name for the specific email application you want and add it to the intent. For Example, if you want to open gmail then you can add `emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm")`

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two separate languages. Please remove the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code hope it will help

```
Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipents ={"your_recepient_email"};
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipents);
            Email.setType("text/html")
            Email.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Send mail"));
```

If you want subject and content use the code like how you added the lines for subject.